# Nested advanced types, inferring that type is key of another object?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a datastructure like this:

```
const VALUES = {
    val1: {...},
    val2: {...},
    val3: {...}
};

const DATA = [
    {
        name: "name1",
        value: "val1" // The value here, is a KEY (not a value) in the "VALUES" object.
    },
    {
        name: "name2",
        value: "val2"
    }
];


type DataType = typeof DATA[number];/*{
    name: string;
    value: string; // I want this to be inferred as "typeof keyof VALUES"
}*/
```

So my question is; is there a way to hint to TypeScript that `value` in `type DataType` should have the type `typeof keyof VALUES` (instead of `string`) without having to explicitly creating the type? Something like this perhaps:

```
const DATA = [
    {
        name: "name1",
        value: (keyof VALUES).val1
    },
    {
        name: "name2",
        value: (keyof VALUES).val2
    }
];
```

Comment: `const DATA = [{ name: "name1", value: "val1" as keyof typeof VALUES }];`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Works perfectly! Put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const DATA = [{ name: "name1", value: "val1" as keyof typeof VALUES }];
```

---

But I'd rather define a type and explicitly use it for `DATA` variable. This way typescript will validate that values are indeed valid keys.